# JS Array allways returns undefined and length = 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

(using Node.js)
Hi, I have an array with users (User class) on it, when I print the array with console.log, it shows the content correctly and shows that it's length is 3, but when i try to get any thing from the array, it returns **undefined** and for *.length, it returns 0. Where's the problem?

```js
exports.users = [];

exports.loadUsers = (callback) => {
    let more = true;
    let i = 0;
     while(more) {
  let us = _usersFolder + "us_" + i + "/";
  if(fs.existsSync(us)) {
   fs.readFile(path.join(us + "personal.json"), (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
     console.log("failed to load file!");
     return;
    }
    let json_personal = JSON.parse(data);
    this.users.push(new User(json_personal));
   });
   i++;
  } else {
   more = false;
  }
    }
    callback();
}


exports.getUserById = (id) => {
    console.log(this.users);
    console.log("length: " + this.users.length);
    console.log(this.users[0]);
 for(let i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
  let u = this.users[i];
  console.log(u.id);
  if(u.id === id) {
   return u;
  }
 }
 return false;
}
```

getUserById is called in the callback, so users are already loaded.

[image]

Comment: It's an object there. Try to print this.users[0].key

Comment: Are all three lines of code sequential?

Comment: Please add more of your actual code.

Comment: the 3 lines are just an example for you to see what each of them returns. it's strange, because it actually works on other functions. Also if I try with a for each, doesn't work.

Comment: I assumed that is not your actual code. That is why I asked for the actual code, though. We cannot help based on "example" code.

Comment: i'll update in asecond

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you are using the 'this' object. It's possible that 'this' makes reference to a different object than the one you stored the array in ('this' varies depending on the scope where you are using it).

I'd need more information to help you.

Comment: this is because i'm in a exports.* method from node

Comment: And where did you define the 'users' array?

Answer (score 0):

```
var users=[{"num":1},{"num":2},{"num":3}];

console.log(this.users);
console.log("length: " + this.users.length);
console.log(this.users[0]);
```

**output**

(3) [Object, Object, Object]

length: 3

Object {a: 1}

Answer (score -1):

I hope you are defining after you print in console.

```js
var users  = [];
console.log(users);
console.log("length: " + users.length);
console.log(users[0]);
users.push(1);
users.push(2);
users.push(3);
```

The output of `console.log()` is misleading; While you log that time there was no value. After that it was added. It prints the **reference of object** , not the state value. So you will see current state value all the time.

Comment: Then why console.log(this.users); works perfect? As you can see in the image, it prints the array correctly, but afterwards it's like the array were empty

Comment: because console.log prints a reference to the object